# pandas fill missing time intervals as given in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame looking like:

| gap_id | species | time_start | time_stop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | wheat | 2021-11-22 00:01:00 | 2021-11-22 00:03:00 |
| 2 | fescue | 2021-12-18 05:52:00 | 2021-12-18 05:53:00 |

I would like to expand the DataFrame such that I get as many rows as the number of minutes between *time_start* and *time_stop* for each *gap_id*:

| gap_id | species | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | wheat | 2021-11-22 00:01:00 |
| 1 | wheat | 2021-11-22 00:02:00 |
| 1 | wheat | 2021-11-22 00:03:00 |
| 2 | fescue | 2021-12-18 05:52:00 |
| 2 | fescue | 2021-12-18 05:53:00 |

I've tried the method `pd.data_range` but I don't know how to couple it with a `groupby` made on *gap_id*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If small DataFrame and performance is not important generate for each row [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and then use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df['time'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['time_start'], x['time_stop'], freq='T'), axis=1)
df = df.drop(['time_start','time_stop'], axis=1).explode('time')

print (df)
   gap_id species                time
0       1   wheat 2021-11-22 00:01:00
0       1   wheat 2021-11-22 00:02:00
0       1   wheat 2021-11-22 00:03:00
1       2  fescue 2021-12-18 05:52:00
1       2  fescue 2021-12-18 05:53:00
```

For large DataFrames repeat indices by difference `start` and `stop` columns in minutes first and then add counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with convert to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) :

```
df['time_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_start'])
df['time_stop'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_stop'])

df = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['time_stop'].sub(df['time_start']).dt.total_seconds() // 60 + 1)]
        .drop('time_stop', axis=1)
        .rename(columns={'time_start':'time'}))
       
td = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='Min')

df['time'] += td
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   gap_id species                time
0       1   wheat 2021-11-22 00:01:00
1       1   wheat 2021-11-22 00:02:00
2       1   wheat 2021-11-22 00:03:00
3       2  fescue 2021-12-18 05:52:00
4       2  fescue 2021-12-18 05:53:00
```